# Manter dados já preenchidos no formulário

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ao trazer o formulário para o usuário preencher, preciso que, se já exista os dados no banco de dados, ele me traga o formulário preenchido com a possibilidade do usuário "editar", mas sempre criando um novo registro e não alterando o já existente.

Obs: Não é o mesmo que usar `{{old('campo')}}` pois é somente para uma *request* que der erro. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

```
<label for="peso">Peso (Kg) : </label>
<input type="text" name="peso" class="form-control" v-model="peso"/>
<label for="altura">Altura (m) : </label>
<input type="text" name="altura" class="form-control" v-model="altura" v-mask="'#.##'"/>
<label for="peso">Idade: </label>
<input type="text" name="idade" class="form-control" v-model="idade"/>
<br/>
```

Comment: Se será um novo registro, não há um `id` associado. Se não há um `id` associado, como saberemos se as informações já constam no banco de dados?

Comment: As informações de Peso, altura e idade estão associadas ao usuário, pelo id de usuário eu veria se já existe dados no banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe o método `replicate` do Model que pode te ajudar, ele cria um clone do modelo não existente no banco. ([link](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate))

Digamos que o seu model é `Informacoes`, no controller você pode verificar se já existe dados no banco e então você replica a última informação.

```
//Exemplo 
public function metodoDoController() {
    $informacao = $usuario->ultimaInformacao();
    $informacao = $informacao->replicate();
    return view('SUA_VIEW', compact('informacao'));
}
```